# cycling through each individual sublist

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sublist

Write a function that takes a list of list of numbers and prints out elements by cycling through each individual sublist.Basically, given an input like:

```
       [
          [1, 2, 3],
          [10, 20, 30],
       ]
```

Print out the first elements of each sublist, followed by the second elements, etc. The expected output is:
           1
           10
           2
           20
           3
           30

Comment: do nested arrays have the same length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple `for` loop?

```js
var arr = [[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30]];


for (var i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    document.write(arr[j][i] + ' ');
  }
}
```

Comment: Which only works if all inner arrays are the same length.

Comment: @Sens Indeed. Note that OP didn't mention anything about different lengths of nested arrays.

Comment: just wanted to add it, so he knows.

Comment: Had an additional question.How complicated can this problem get further will it have the same sequence if output or will it be different

Comment: @sens  Will the above give the same output in the console as well

Comment: @neilmartis What do you mean by *output will be different*? How different?

Comment: How complicated level of difficulty can this problem be?

Comment: @neilmartis It may be difficult, if the nested arrays have different lengths.

Comment: @sens If I replace document.write with Console.log will it give the same output

Comment: @kinduser if different arrays have different length but the sequence of numbers be the same how will it display in console.log

Comment: @kinduser do you have the same exp via console.log to see it I didn't understand what you meant sorry abt it

Comment: @kinduser just need to understand the scenarios that's all how complicated it can be

Comment: @neilmartis You can check by yourself what will be the output if the nested arrays are different :P